# Ошибка конвертирования из .ui в .py

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

При попытке конвертировать файл формата .ui в формат .py возникает следующая ошибка:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль.

Полный текст ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как её исправить? Пути PATH вроде прописал
Вот скрины:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наберите с консоли (CMD) `pyuic5 test.ui -o test.py -x`

Comment: @S.Nick не работает, ошибка та же

Answer (score 0):

Исправил ошибку тем, что запустил команду:

> pyuic5 test.ui -o test.py

Через terminal в PyCharm. Просто положил файл в директорию со всеми, запустил команду и файл конвертировался